# Foundation Grid column taking up whole width regardless of requested width of grid item

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for Sites version 6.4.1, and upon updating to this version from version 6.3.*, my grid system is messed up. I need to use the legacy float grid instead of the new grid they introduced in 6.4, but the documentation indicates that 6.4 should be plenty backwards compatible.

If I have a row that looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-8 medium-centered columns">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The center column will take up the entire page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you're using the proper grid, Foundation 6.4 has 3 grids available: XY (default), Float and Flex.

The code in your sample belongs to the "traditional" **Float Grid**, while the default grid in this new version (from June 27th) is XY Grid. So you have two options:

1. Change your markup according to the new XY grid (take a look to http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html )
2. Change the framework to use the *Float Grid*, now this depends on how you downloaded the framework in first place; if you used the precompiled package, you should go to http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation to customize (basically just selecting the Float Grid and download a new package); if you used the SASS version, just go to the `_settings.scss` file, find the variable to select the proper grid and rebuild.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what variable I should select?

Comment: At the end of `_settings.scss` file, you'll find a section named *Xy Grid*, in that section, set the var `$xy-grid` to **false**; depending on your setup, you will have also to edit the `app.scss` file, uncommenting the line where shows `@include foundation-grid;`, and commenting the one with `@include foundation-xy-grid-classes;` (remember to rebuild framework)